# AWS Step Function workflow is showing failed status when excuting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/#) tutorial for creating a sample workflow with AWS Step Functions and AWS Lambda. I have done everything as per the blog, but when I run it is showing failed status at the "Is Case Resolved" stage.

**Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebmbb.png

I have done like below:

`Step1`: Created a role in AWS Management Console and copied the Role ARN value.

`Step2`: Created a new State Machine with the ASL code provided in the blog and added the Role ARN value.

`Step3`: Created all the 5 AWS Lambda Functions

`Step4`: Edited the state Machine and added the Resource value of the Lambda function.

`Step5`: Executed the workflow with the below code:

```json
{
    "inputCaseID": "001"
}
```

**My ASL code in state machine:**

```json
    {
      "Comment": "A simple AWS Step Functions state machine that automates a call center support session.",
      "StartAt": "Open Case",
      "States": {
        "Open Case": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:AccountId:function:OpenCaseFunction",
          "Next": "Assign Case"
        }, 
        "Assign Case": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:AccountId:function:AssignCaseFunction",
          "Next": "Work on Case"
        },
        "Work on Case": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:AccountId:function:WorkOnCaseFunction",
          "Next": "Is Case Resolved"
        },
        "Is Case Resolved": {
            "Type" : "Choice",
            "Choices": [ 
              {
                "Variable": "$.Status",
                "NumericEquals": 1,
                "Next": "Close Case"
              },
              {
                "Variable": "$.Status",
                "NumericEquals": 0,
                "Next": "Escalate Case"
              }
          ]
        },
         "Close Case": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:AccountId:function:CloseCaseFunction",
          "End": true
        },
        "Escalate Case": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:AccountId:function:EscalateCaseFunction",
          "Next": "Fail"
        },
        "Fail": {
          "Type": "Fail",
          "Cause": "Engage Tier 2 Support."    }   
      }
    }
```

Error showing:

```
{
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'Is Case Resolved' (entered at the event id #17). Invalid path '$.Status': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value."
}
```

**OpenCaseFunction**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // Create a support case using the input as the case ID, then return a confirmation message   
   var myCaseID = event.inputCaseID;
   var myMessage = "Case " + myCaseID + ": opened...";   
   var result = {Case: myCaseID, Message: myMessage};
   callback(null, result);    
};
```

**AssignCaseFunction**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
    // Assign the support case and update the status message    
    var myCaseID = event.Case;    
    var myMessage = event.Message + "assigned...";    
    var result = {Case: myCaseID, Message: myMessage};
    callback(null, result);        
};
```

**WorkOnCaseFunction**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
    // Generate a random number to determine whether the support case has been resolved, then return that value along with the updated message.
    var min = 0;
    var max = 1;    
    var myCaseStatus = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    var myCaseID = event.Case;
    var myMessage = event.Message;
    if (myCaseStatus == 1) {
        // Support case has been resolved    
        myMessage = myMessage + "resolved...";
    } else if (myCaseStatus == 0) {
        // Support case is still open
        myMessage = myMessage + "unresolved...";
    } 
    var result = {Case: myCaseID, Status : myCaseStatus, Message: myMessage};
    callback(null, result); 
};
```

**EscalateCaseFunction**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
    // Escalate the support case 
    var myCaseID = event.Case;    
    var myCaseStatus = event.Status;    
    var myMessage = event.Message + "escalating.";    
    var result = {Case: myCaseID, Status : myCaseStatus, Message: myMessage};
    callback(null, result);
};
```

**CloseCaseFunction**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => { 
    // Close the support case    
    var myCaseStatus = event.Status;    
    var myCaseID = event.Case;    
    var myMessage = event.Message + "closed.";    
    var result = {Case: myCaseID, Status : myCaseStatus, Message: myMessage};
    callback(null, result);
};
```

What I am missing in this?

Comment: `Always mask your Account ID`. I am assuming this an [Express Workflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-standard-vs-express.html), So you can share the logs of the state where it failed. Plus check the lambda named `function:WorkOnCaseFunction`  what it is returning, because the further choice depends on the output of this function.

Comment: @samtoddler I have created a standard workflow and output of WorkOnCaseFunction is success. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R2Wg.png Should we need an express workflow for this?

Comment: @Mathew check the ouput of the mentioned lambda, what it is?, you can check the logs of the state as well why it is cancelled.

Comment: @samtoddler Could you please check this screenshot, https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Tel.png

Comment: @Mattew Pans as you see in the screenshot you shared the input is not correct. It should be something like in [this screenshot](https://d1.awsstatic.com/Getting%20Started/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/06f.6f215e08011458e67aac1ddded7b1a26b9aef24b.png) where you have `Status` field inside the json. So check your `function:WorkOnCaseFunction`  output and try to use the code provided in the guide.

Comment: @samtoddler In the tutorial on Step 6 (Execute your Workflow), they have provided a sample input, I am using that. 
{
"inputCaseID": "001"
}

Comment: @Mathew Pans the input is fine, but `WorkOnCaseFunction` lambda function is create another intermediate input for your `Choice state` which needs t he input in a certain format as depicted in [the screenshot](https://d1.awsstatic.com/Getting%20Started/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/06f.6f215e08011458e67aac1ddded7b1a26b9aef24b.png).

Comment: the input to the `choice` state should be something like `{Case: 001, Status : 0 or 1, Message:<custom message>}`

Comment: @Mathew Pans can you share the code for `WorkOnCaseFunction` function?

Comment: @samtoddler I have edited the question with `WorkOnCaseFunction` function, could you please check the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The named `WorkOnCaseFunction` is not producing correct output which should be something like below structure.

```json
{ Case: '001', Status: 0, Message: 'hellounresolved...' }
```

It is consumed by the `choice` state which tries to fetch `Status` by using `jsonpath` `$.Status`.

If it is not present then it errors out and cancels the further execution of the statemachine.

`For example`:

Below is my state machine `without` `DefaultState` for `Choice` State, Either `Fail` or `Success` depending on the output produced by
`function:mytestfunction` which can be either `0` or `1`.

```json
{
  "Comment": "An example of the Amazon States Language using a choice state.",
  "StartAt": "FirstState",
  "States": {
    "FirstState": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:1234567890:function:mytestfunction",
      "Next": "ChoiceState"
    },
    "ChoiceState": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.Status",
          "NumericEquals": 1,
          "Next": "Success"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.Status",
          "NumericEquals": 0,
          "Next": "Failed"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Success": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Comment": "Success",
      "End": true
    },
    "Failed": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Comment": "Failed",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

`function:mytestfunction` code

```json
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
    // Generate a random number to determine whether the support case has been resolved, then return that value along with the updated message.
    var min = 0;
    var max = 1;    
    var myCaseStatus = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    var myCaseID = "001";
    var myMessage = "hello";
    if (myCaseStatus == 1) {
        // Support case has been resolved    
        myMessage = myMessage + "resolved...";
    } else if (myCaseStatus == 0) {
        // Support case is still open
        myMessage = myMessage + "unresolved...";
    } 
    var result = {Case: myCaseID, Status : myCaseStatus, Message: myMessage};
    console.log('result: %s', result);
    callback(null, result); 
};
```

I just added a `log` message what is being returned to `stepfunction`, plus just for testing I made `message` and `case` static.

That gives me the output like

[image]

Then this output from lambda is being consumed by `Choice` state and it tries to fetch just `Status` out of the following json which is produced by `function:mytestfunction`

```json
{ Case: '001', Status: 0, Message: 'hellounresolved...' }
```

[image]

Now you can see what is going wrong with the lambda named `WorkOnCaseFunction`. It is not producing the output in the above format and your state machine is failing.

Comment: I have added all the function code in the question. Could you please have a quick look and tell me the reason why `WorkOnCaseFunction` is not producing correct output?

Comment: can you add `console.log('result: %s', result);`  to `WorkOnCaseFunction` function and share the logs output from `CloudWatch` ?

Comment: I have added the console, but from where I can see the output?

Comment: @MatthewPans [Accessing Amazon CloudWatch logs for AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html)

Comment: I have cleared all the logs presently on it and run a new one: Following is the log events screenshot, could you please have a look? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm4Z2.png

Comment: @MatthewPans all the screenshots you have shared collectively they dont make sense. [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Tel.png) you shared is for state machine error logs, which has `Hello from Lambda` text,  but none of the functions mentioned above has this message and [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm4Z2.png) you shared  for `WorkOnCaseFunction` which has the `console.log` and it doesn't print anything in the logs.

Comment: I accidentally deleted one role from AWS Management Console, is this cause any issue? https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X3zl.png

Comment: @MatthewPans no that's not related

Comment: I think the issue is from the initial stage. For the `OpenCaseFunction` the response I am getting is `{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}`

Comment: As per the `OpenCaseFunction` code response should be like this:  `Case: 001, Message: opened...`

Comment: What I missing here. I am passing the input like this: `{
"inputCaseID": "001"
}`

Comment: Log screenshot of `OpenCaseFunction`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSHaZ.png

Comment: @MatthewPans according to the code I see , which you shared <{Case: myCaseID, Status : myCaseStatus, Message: myMessage}> this is getting calculated in `WorkOnCaseFunction`. It is adding `Status` which we need.

Comment: We are getting wrong output even from the first stage(OpenCaseFunction). Expected output is `Case: 001, Message: opened...`, but I am getting the below output: `{   "statusCode": 200,   "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\"" }`. So the issue is started from there. Any idea why the wrong output is getting from initial stage?

Comment: @MatthewPans check the lambda ARNs in the statemachine definition if they are correct, it seems like the lambda which is needed is not there.

Comment: I will check that, one more question: which type we need to select for creating a state machine? Standard or Express?

Comment: you can check out the comparison here [Standard vs. Express Workflows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-standard-vs-express.html). Depending on your needs you can choose.

Comment: Finally fixed the issue. After creating a lambda function we need to deploy it. That was the reason for wrong output. I have done that and it is working fine now. Could you please add it on your answer and thank you very much for the support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003106/how-to-invoke-a-lambda-function-using-the-request-id-and-update-the-running-stat

Answer (score 0):

Try this one - it works perfectly and been tested many times.

[image]

Its similar - but the difference is the Lambda functions were written using the Java run-time API. It also show you how to invoke other AWS Services - such as Amazon DynamoDB - from a Lambda function:

[Create AWS serverless workflows by using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_workflows_stepfunctions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915029/how-to-call-a-step-funtion-from-node-js-lambda-function?noredirect=1#comment118293176_66915029