# How to invoke a lambda function using the Request ID and update the running status?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which returns the `Request ID` of the lambda execution. Also in that lambda function I have added a countdown using the `setTimeout` function. If the countdown end it will fire a new function. I need to implement 2 things over here:

1. Get the `Request ID` response before countdown starts(without any delay). Currently, it is returning the `Request ID` only after the completion of the lambda function execution(After the completion of the count down).
2. I need to call the same lambda function(if the count down is not over) using the `Request ID` and add time to the countdown or kill the entire lambda function and stop firing the new function.

**Is the above requirements are able to do with a lambda function?**

**My Current lambda function codes are added below:**

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    var duration = event.time;
    var emergencyType = event.type;
    var emergencyStatus = event.status;
    var requestId = event.requestid;
    if (requestId != 0) 
    {
      //how to get access to the running lambda function
    }
    else
    {
      var apiRequestId = context.awsRequestId;
      var output = "Request ID: " + apiRequestId;
      callback(null, output);
    }
    //how to return the Request ID before starting countdown
    setTimeout(TriggerAlert, duration, emergencyType);
};

function TriggerAlert(arg) {
  console.log(`arg was => ${arg}`);
  //doing some importent actions here
}
```

**Sample Input:**

```
{
    "requestid": "0",   //0 means new execution, otherwise a running execution
    "time": "3000",
    "type": "watchme",
    "status": "add"    //add or kill will be the possible statuses
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
"Request ID: 087b1124-ea8e-4d3c-8f50-9ccc44e9aea2"
```

Comment: I'd love to know why you are doing this. I can't imagine anything that would require a mechanism like this. If you need to "orchestrate" multiple Lambdas, you might want to have a look at [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).

Comment: @Jens I am trying to implement a watch me feature (security feature). Suppose a user starts a watch me with 5 min; then, I will call a lambda function and start a count down there and return the request-id. If the count down over, the lambda function will trigger a function that will send emergency alerts. If the user is safe, they will cancel the watch me; at that instance, I will cancel the current running lambda function and stopped the emergency function execution. Is this possible using a lambda function? I am very new to this.

Comment: It would not work with just a Lambda. And even then it is more like a hack. Also keep in mind: a Lambda can not run for more than 15 minutes. So your "watch me" feature wouldn't support anything longer than that. As I said before, you might have more luck with Step Functions. They are like workflows and have a ["Wait"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html). Your workflow could have to Lambdas. The first one will callback to your user (WebSocket?) and then set the "wait" for the second Lambda.

Comment: @Jens So I need to create a step function with 2 lambda functions. On the first lambda, I need to read the user's input and set the wait for the second lambda. On the second lambda, I need to add the emergency function executions. So is it possible to return the instance id of the step function before the wait execution, and is it possible to call the same step function with that request-id and update or kill the current execution?